# Convert Ruby ActiveRecord::Migration syntax to SQL syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Is there a way to convert the syntax of schema.

For example how can I convert this to sql syntax?

```
create_table :authors do |t|
  t.string :name, null: false
end
```

should return

```
CREATE TABLE authors(name varchar NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly convert Active Record migrations into sql, however, you can set your schema output to raw sql:
`config/application.rb`

```
 config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

Another way of doing this may be just running the migration, rolling it back with `db:rollback` and looking into your log file for raw sql.

There are multiple ways to do what are you trying to do with custom rake tasks. For example, [here is a very nice article](http://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/07/29/how-to-use-rake-tasks-to-generate-migration-sql/) on it.

[Further reading](http://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/07/29/how-to-use-rake-tasks-to-generate-migration-sql/) that may be useful.